# SHELL take off all zeros on the left of a string

Tags: shell

I'm trying to execute a shell script where I need to transform a string that looks like this: "00001" into one that looks like this; "1" and take off all the zero on the left..

Any ideas how to do this in the simplest way possible?

Thanks!

Comment: got it ;): echo "00001" | sed 's/0*//'

Comment: That will turn `205` into `25`. Probably not what you mean.

Comment: yours is not safe, try it with `2000000`, you will see.

Comment: no it works; the man says:Substitute the replacement string for the *first* instance of the regular expression in the pattern space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bash built-in:

```
> echo $((0000000001))
1
```

If you're using numbers greater than 7, they'll be interpreted as octal, so you'll need to specify base ten explicitly:

```
    > val=00010
    > echo $((val))
    8
    > echo $((10#$val))
    10
```

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
kent$  echo "000001"|awk '{$0*=1}1'
1
```

or by substitution:

```
kent$  echo "000001"|sed 's/^0*//' 
1
```

Answer (score 1):

echo "00001" | sed 's/0*//' will return "1". s/ means search and replace, it searches for 0 and replaces them with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `#` operator with parameter expansion. You'll need to enable extended glob support first (making this non-POSIX), as basic patterns aren't powerful enough to match a string of 0s.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ foo="000001"
$ echo "${foo##+(0)}"
1
$ bar=${foo##+(0)}
$ echo "$foo -- $bar"
000001 -- 1
```

Another non-POSIX option is the substitution operator. This doesn't require extended pattern support.

```
$ echo "${foo//#0}"
```

Comment: Did you try this?  `${foo##0}` removes the first 0, leaving `00001`  Perhaps you meant `${foo##*0}`, but that would remove everything up to the _last_ 0, so it would change `00102` to `2`.

Comment: I make this mistake more often than I care to admit. You need to enable extended glob support